# Modifying state for specific item in array in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, state

I can't quite wrap my head around the boilerplate of [redux](/questions/tagged/redux). I looked up common patterns for [immutable modifying of state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/) but issue is, all these patterns simply push towards the end and not for a specific index.

Before I'll go into actual code, here's what the **structure of the state** looks like for better imagination *(pseudo-code)*:

```
state = {
   quizMenu: {...},
   quizEditor: Array<Question>,

    > type Question = {
        id: number,
        question: string,
        questionOptions: Array<QuestionOption>,
      }

        > type QuestionOption = {
           id: number,
           optionText: string,
           isValid: boolean,
          }
}
```

[image]

Hopefully it makes sense. I have created an action for adding questions, which works fine. Now I'm **trying to create an action for adding option to an already existing question**, but I can't wrap my head around how to in the nested arrays of objects.

Here's how my action in question is defined:

```
const AQO = 'ADD_QUESTION_OPTION';

/*
 * @param questionId - ID of the question we're accesssing in quizEditor array
 * @param id - id of the option we're adding (handled in component)
*/
const actionAddQuestionOption = createAction(
  AQO, 
  (questionId: number, id: number) => ({ 
    payload: {
      id,
      optionText: 'New option',
      isValid: false,
      questionId,
    },
  })
);
```

Now my reducer is the following way:

```
const reducer = createReducer({//...}, {
   [actionAddQuestionOption.type]: (state, action) => ({
     ...state,
     quizEditor: [...state.quizEditor][action.payload.questionId].questionOptions.push({
        id: action.payload.id,
        optionText: action.payload.optionText,
        isValid: action.payload.isValid,
     })
   })
}
```

This just ends up in this monster type-error: https://pastebin.com/raw/pBbnxcQp

But I'm pretty sure I'm accessing the Array inside the array of objects incorrectly.

```
quizEditor: [...state.quizEditor][action.payload.questionId].questionOptions
```

Does anyone know what would be the proper way of going about accessing it? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) which has [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) built in you can just mutate the state directly and it will transform it into an immutable update internally

```js
const reducer = createReducer({
  [actionAddQuestionOption.type]: (state, { payload: { questionId, ...option }}) => {
    const question = state.questionquizEditor(question => question.id === questionId)
    question.questionOptions.push(option)
  }
})
```

The way to make it an immuable update is like this

```js
const reducer = createReducer({
  [actionAddQuestionOption.type]: (state, { payload: { questionId, ...option } }) => ({
    ...state,
    quizEditor: state.quizEditor.map(question =>
      (question.id === questionId
        ? {
          ...question,
          questionOptions: [...question.questionOptions, option],
        }
        : question)),
  }),
})
```

Comment: Hey everyone, I've solved the question thanks to AsafAviv's help, either way, just leaving this here as a **working example** in case anyone might find it useful: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-bardeen-98ggl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

the `push` method of `Array` returns the new length of the array not the array itself. What you can do is just `concat` the new object to the array which in turn will return the new array with the new question option.

```
[...state.quizEditor][action.payload.questionId].questionOptions.concat({
        id: action.payload.id,
        optionText: action.payload.optionText,
        isValid: action.payload.isValid,
     })
```

Furthermore, we have to modify only that property in the state with our new array:

```
const reducer = createReducer({
  //...}, {
  [actionAddQuestionOption.type]: (state, action) => {
    const quizEditor = [...state.quizEditor];
    quizEditor[action.payload.questionId].questionOptions = quizEditor[
      action.payload.questionId
    ].questionOptions.concat({
      id: action.payload.id,
      optionText: action.payload.optionText,
      isValid: action.payload.isValid
    });

    return {
      ...state,
      quizEditor
    };
  }
});
```

Thanks to immer in redux toolkit we can make it more readable:

```
const reducer = createReducer({
  //...}, {
  [actionAddQuestionOption.type]: (state, action) => {
    const question = state.quizEditor[action.payload.questionId];
    question.questionOptions = [
      ...question.questionOptions,
      {
        id: action.payload.id,
        optionText: action.payload.optionText,
        isValid: action.payload.isValid
      }
    ];

    return state;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yup, that's my bad for overlooking. Was actually half way through editing my question. Either way, sadly even with your solution i still get a similar type-error as mentioned in my original question

Comment: Yes, I now know the problem! Give me a sec rewriting the solution :)

Comment: This should return the modified state. Instead of only `state` I'm guessing easiest way would be to splice the array until `optionId` and spread `...until splice, new item, ...after splice`?

Comment: It is returning the modified state. Thanks to Immer  we can do this and will get an immutable result regardless. Check out their [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer) for more info.